# combine some data in 1 arrray if in same id on multidimesensional array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array `$voucher_data` with this following array :

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "519"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "525"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

In my array `[0]` and `[1]` the `voucher_menu_id` is `3`. They have same `voucher_menu_id` and also `[2]` and `[3]` is `4`

So i want to combine the `variant_menu_id` become 1 array become like this :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    array(2){
      string(1) "2"
      string(1) "6"
    }
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "521"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    array(2){
      string(1) "1"
      string(1) "4"
    }
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
  }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "519"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(5) {
    ["voucher_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["menu_id"]=>
    string(3) "525"
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["variant_menu_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["voucher_menu_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
}
```

Guys can you help me how to combine it?

Thank you (:

Comment: use the usual `$array[$v['variant_menu_id']] = $v['variant_menu_id']` assignment

Comment: can you help me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like the comment above, just use your `voucher_menu_id` as your key into assigning the new container. Use that so that it'll be group when you loop:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($voucher_data as $v) {
    if(empty($new_array[$v['voucher_menu_id']])) { // if empty initialize
        $new_array[$v['voucher_menu_id']] = $v; // base array group
        $new_array[$v['voucher_menu_id']]['variant_menu_id'] = array(); // intialize container
    }
    // push id
    $new_array[$v['voucher_menu_id']]['variant_menu_id'][] = $v['variant_menu_id'];
}

$new_array = array_values($new_array); // array reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this might work:

```
$output = array();
foreach ($array as $entry) {
    // make the variant_menu_id an array
    $entry['variant_menu_id'] = (array) $entry['variant_menu_id'];

    $key = $entry['voucher_menu_id'];
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $output)) {
        // create a new entry in the output array using the entire $entry
        $output[$key] = $entry;
        continue;
    }

    // otherwise, add your variant menu ID to the existing values
    $output[$key]['variant_menu_id'] = array_merge($output[$key]['variant_menu_id'], $entry['variant_menu_id']);
}
```

This will essentially create a new array by grouping entries by their `voucher_menu_id`, and adding `variant_menu_id` values into an array in the `$output`.

Comment: i can get the array in `variant_menu_id` buy my array become weird, because the position of the array become disordered. [3]  [4] [1] and [2]

Comment: You need to sort it afterwards